# trouble referencing JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, reference

I am still new to `JSON` so I have a probably very stupid question. How do I reference 
`list.data[0].bom-item.descriptor`? The alert statement I created didn't work for me. Thanks for help.

```
var txt='{"list": {"data": [{"bom-item": {"dmsID": 3949,"bomPath": "3951B3949","workspaceType": 6,"workspaceID": 8,"bomDepthLevel": 1,"quantity": 1,"formattedQuantity": "1.0","descriptor": "500-0059-000 - FCI, P681-C01 SKU77 (900-60681-0077-400) [REV:D]","revision": "D","units": "EA","itemNumber": 1,"assembly": false,"cost": 0,"isPinned": false,"quoteID": 0,"isUsingDefaultQuote": false,"leaf": false,"redlinedCost": -1,"redlineAddition": false,"redlineAgainstVersion": -1,"redlineDeletion": false,"totalWeight": 1,"lifecycleStatus": "Production","hasSourcing": false,"fields": null}}]}}'



alert(txt.list.data[0].bom-item.descriptor);
```

Comment: what happens when you run that alert statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, `txt` is just a string, so it has no JSON object properties. You need to use `JSON.parse()` to translate it to a JSON object (and use index notation as stated in another answer — the hyphen `-` is what's causing the trouble):

```
<  yourObj = JSON.parse('{"list": {"data": [{"bom-item": {"dmsID": 3949,"bomPath": "3951B3949","workspaceType": 6,"workspaceID": 8,"bomDepthLevel": 1,"quantity": 1,"formattedQuantity": "1.0","descriptor": "500-0059-000 - FCI, P681-C01 SKU77 (900-60681-0077-400) [REV:D]","revision": "D","units": "EA","itemNumber": 1,"assembly": false,"cost": 0,"isPinned": false,"quoteID": 0,"isUsingDefaultQuote": false,"leaf": false,"redlinedCost": -1,"redlineAddition": false,"redlineAgainstVersion": -1,"redlineDeletion": false,"totalWeight": 1,"lifecycleStatus": "Production","hasSourcing": false,"fields": null}}]}}')
>  [object Object]
<  yourObj.list.data[0]["bom-item"].descriptor
>  "500-0059-000 - FCI, P681-C01 SKU77 (900-60681-0077-400) [REV:D]"
```

Info on the `JSON` object [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Answer (score 1):

`bom-item` is not a legal Javascript identifier.

Instead, you need to use indexer notation:

```
txt.list.data[0]["bom-item"].descriptor
```

Or, better yet, use camelCase instead.